# Xcode Core Data Displaying all Entities in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

I want is to list all my "Guests" from core data in a label. I am using the following code but i just get "Guest : (null) in my UILabel. Why?

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = 
                    (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Guests"
                      inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSString *Guests;
NSString *stringText;
stringText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", stringText, 
                [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"Guest : %@" , Guests]];
self.ListAllLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Guest : %@\n"];
[_ListAllLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[_ListAllLabel sizeToFit];

 for(NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedObjects)
 {
    {         
       NSLog(@"Name:%@\n Last Name %@\n", [obj valueForKey:@"name"],
                                          [obj valueForKey:@"lastname"]);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing an object using the format specifier such as %@ just calls an inbuilt method description on a object. 
Eg [Guests Description];
Every NSObject implements this method. You should not use this to display in a label as it would result in sometimes junk values.

To solve your problem just use simple string concatenation.

in your FOR loop where you NSLog just try this

```
     NSString*guestString =@"";
        for(NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedObjects)

        {

            guestString =[guestString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - Name %@ -Last Name \n",[obj valueForKey:@"name"],[obj valueForKey:@"lastname"]]]
        }
self.ListAllLabel.text = guestString
```

Comment: Thanking all answers and trying to work it out… NavinDev thank you for your solution …i finally got it to work thanks to you…have no more compiler warnings but i must admit i have to understand that what it is that i am trying to do…cheers

Comment: Thats okay , CoreData takes a while to understand. But once you get a hang of it , its just easy after that. You can check out my [BLOG](http://affine.co/what-the-context/) it would help you get a hang of what your doing in your code. Cheers

Comment: very cool and smooth looking blog about core data by NavinDev by the way…thanks...

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this line is a problem:

```
self.ListAllLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Guest : %@\n"];
```

You are missing the value to fill in for the `%@` in your format string.

Comment: thank you Jeff... tried and it didn't work but it corrected one of my compiler warnings but i have one left on the line above….i am still getting

Comment: Never ignore compiler warnings.  They are telling you something important.  What warnings are you getting?

Comment: yeah..i know..i have one left on the line "stringText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", stringText, [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"Guest : %@" , Guests]];"…data argument not used by format string…i don't get it...

Comment: Your format string has one argument - %@ - and you are passing it two.  Look carefully at that line...

Comment: @JeffLoughlin doest your answer is currect do you think that is setting value..? where is setting variable of %@.? that gives error.

Comment: Also ask yourself where Guests and stringText get their values from...(hint: nowhere)

Comment: @NitinGohel: I'm trying to gently lead the OP to the answer, not spoon feed it (i.e. "teach a man to fish...")

Comment: i am also said OP that your asnwer having wrong format code.